# Can't access MySQL 8.0 INFORMATION_SCHEMA from MyODBC link

Tags: mysql, odbc, information-schema

I'm using MS Access as a front end to a MySQL database which is currently running on 5.7.30, which is working as expected. I have a test server for MySQL 8.0 and I'm not getting any data returned when accessing the INFORMATION_SCHEMA via my odbc. This query works fine via odbc on the 5.7.30 server. I have no issues accessing my main database via odbc on the MySQL 8.0 server.

I can access the same data from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA on the MySQL 8.0 server, via the same query in PHPMyAdmin using the same user account.

I'm using the "MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver" in the connection string in both instances.

Any idea if this is a configuration issue or something new with 8.0?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was the COLLATE of the CHARACTER SET, which had changed from utf8_general_ci to utf8_tolower_ci. utf8_tolower_ci didn't work over the odbc connection.